# Refer to method from containing scope in resource in chef recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

In a chef recipe I define a helper method like:

```rb
def my_service_config(description, args="")
  {
    Unit: {
      Description: description,
    },
    Service: {
      Type: 'simple',
      ExecStart: "/usr/sbin/my-service-script #{args}",
      Restart: 'on-failure',
    }
  }
end

systemd_unit "my-service.service" do
  content my_service_config("my description", "--some-flag")
  action :create
end
```

But when I run chef I get an error like:

```
NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `my_service_config' for Chef::Resource::SystemdUnit
```

How can I properly refer to the `my_service_config` method from inside the `systemd_unit` resource block?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Chef [libraries](https://docs.chef.io/libraries/) to write pure Ruby code. You can extend the functionality of a Chef recipe using methods such as `my_service_config` in a library. This method can be put into a "helper" file in `libraries/` directory.

For example in `libraries/helper.rb`:

```rb
class Chef::Recipe
  def my_service_config(description, args="")
    {
      Unit: {
        Description: description,
      },
      Service: {
        Type: 'simple',
        ExecStart: "/usr/sbin/my-service-script #{args}",
        Restart: 'on-failure',
      }
    }
  end
end
```

Then in recipe:

```rb
service_content = my_service_config("my description", "--some-flag")

systemd_unit "my-service.service" do
  content service_content
  action :create
end
```

Comment: that's kind of inconvenient when the function is only used in a single recipe, and may refer to local variables in that recipe.

Comment: If you've seen the linked documentation - *A library allows arbitrary Ruby code to be included in a cookbook*. If its inconvenient to you, you could try filing bug/feature to allow this from recipes.

Comment: Better to throw it into something like `module MyHelpers` and then `Chef::DSL::Universal.include(:MyHelpers)` as the last line of the library file